# Open webpage in browser by setting cookies for authentication in java

Tags: java

I am using only core java. I need to open webpage in browser example : (http://www.abcxxx.com/xyz/abc) by setting cookies to authenticate the user.

My aim is to open the given webpage in browser without giving credentials. (It should authenticate by passing cookies).

I have tried to use `desktop.browse(new URI(url));` to open the webpage in browser but here i am not able to set the cookies to authenticate the user.

I am using only core java.

Can you help here ? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What version of _core java_ are you using?

Comment: i am using java 1.8 version

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately setting cookies when you open an URL in an external web browser is not possible as the web browser only gets the URL from your program.
Opening a web browser and opening a specific URL is already complicated enough for Java, as it has to work on multiple platforms and with hundred of different web browsers.
For some specific web browser on a specific platform there may be a way to set a cookie, but in general you only have the URL.

Therefore the common way is to embed the authentication information into the URL and use this data on server side for authentication, oder convert on server side the URL parameters to an authentication cookie.
This could be done by a little script of server side that reads the URL data, sets the cookie in the response and redirects to the real target page.

Alternatively you could do the authentication in your Java application until you get some sort of session-id. And the use the session-id as URL parameter.